# How to log in with one account and access a db with another account

Tags: sql-server, security, ssms

I log in to SSMS with one set of credentials, no problem. Then I want to access several databases in a script but one of the databases requires different credentials. Is there a way to specify different credentials within the script when accessing a database?

Comment: `EXECUTE AS LOGIN`/`EXECUTE AS USER`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way.

Try with `EXECUTE AS`, see the snippet below.

```sql
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'your login name';  
EXECUTE AS USER = 'your user name';
```

See more on 
[EXECUTE AS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)